# Issue with returning array in function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

i have a problem with the returning array in function.
The compiler says :

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:52:13: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ']' token main.cpp: In function 'double
>   Area(Trapec*, int)': main.cpp:65:12: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ']' token   return p[];

Thats my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Trapec
{
    double a=0;
    double b=0;
    double h=0;
};

double Area(Trapec);   

int main()
{
    int br;
    cout<<"Vuvedete broq na trapecite : ";
    cin>>br;
    // double S=0,min=0;
    //  double areas[50];
    Trapec p[50];
    for(int i=0;i<=br;i++){
        cout<<"Vuvedete a : ";
        cin>>p[i].a;
        cout<<"Vuvedete b : ";
        cin >>p[i].b;
        cout<<"Vuvedete h: ";
        cin>>p[i].h;
    }

    Area(p[]);

    return 0;
}

double Area(Trapec p[], int br)
{
    double S=0;
    double areas[50];
    for(int i=0;i<=br;i++){
        S=p[i].a + p[i].b + p[i].h;
        areas[i] = S;
    }
    return p[];
}
```

Comment: Hint: In C++ don't use C style arrays. Use containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: Another hint - always program in English.

Comment: Instead of `Area(p[]);` it should be `Area(p);`

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code:

1. Your function declaration and definition function are different `double Area(Trapec);` and `double Area(Trapec p[], int br)` are two different functions.
2. Loop end condition is wrong(`for(int i=0;i<=br;i++)`), in this case it will have +1 iteration more then you entered, has to be `for(int i=0;i<br;i++)`, `i<br` instead of `i<=br`.
3. Your parameter `p`(`double Area(Trapec p[], int br)`) accepts array, also compiler accepts it as pointer, so there is no need to return value, p will change all data of passed array, change code of `Area(...)` to:

   `void Area(Trapec p[], int br)
   {
       double S=0;
       double areas[50];
       for(int i=0; i<=br ;i++)
       {
           S=p[i].a + p[i].b + p[i].h;
           areas[i] = S;
       }
   }`
4. Pass argument is wrong, you can't pass like `Area(p[]);`, and there has to be second parameter `br`. You need to pass as simple `Area(p,br);`.

So finally your code will look like:

```
struct Trapec
{
    double a=0;
    double b=0;
    double h=0;
};

void Area(Trapec p[], int br);

int main()
{
    int br;
    cout<<"Vuvedete broq na trapecite : ";
    cin>>br;

    Trapec p[50];
    for(int i=0;i<br;i++){
        cout<<"Vuvedete a : ";
        cin>>p[i].a;
        cout<<"Vuvedete b : ";
        cin >>p[i].b;
        cout<<"Vuvedete h: ";
        cin>>p[i].h;
    }

    Area(p, br);

    return 0;
}

void Area(Trapec p[], int br)
{
    double S=0;
    double areas[50];
    for(int i=0; i<=br ;i++)
    {
        S=p[i].a + p[i].b + p[i].h;
        areas[i] = S;
    }
}
```

And when input test data output looks like:

```
Vuvedete broq na trapecite : 2
Vuvedete a : 1
Vuvedete b : 1
Vuvedete h: 1
Vuvedete a : 2
Vuvedete b : 2
Vuvedete h: 2
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Thank you but my task is to print the array on the console and after that i should check the min element in the array

Comment: @Stanislav Well, your question has no word about it!